# How often were medieval scribal abbreviations used?

Tags: medieval-latin, abbreviations

In the preface to [*The elements of abbreviation in medieval Latin paleography*](https://kuscholarworks.ku.edu/bitstream/handle/1808/1821/47cappelli.pdf?sequence=3), Adriano Cappelli writes

> Take a foreign language, write it in an unfamiliar script, abbreviating every third word, and you have the compound puzzle that is the medieval Latin manuscript.

I would assume that this is just a joke, but after some reading of the wide use of [scribal abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribal_abbreviation) (*sigla*, including truncations and contractions) elsewhere, I've had second thoughts. While it would clearly be impossible to pin down an exact percentage, is Cappelli's joke close enough? Were a substantial amount of words in medieval Latin abbreviated, or only a relatively small amount?

I understand from [*Scrittura e Civilta*](http://www.mgh-bibliothek.de/dokumente/a/a070223.pdf) that the use and type of scribal abbreviations varied throughout the Middle Ages to such an extent that they can be used to approximately date manuscripts, but I do not think that this should impact the question too much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, Cappelli is basically right (which is perhaps not surprising, he being an authoritative figure in the field of palaeography).

Every third word is probably above average, but in most documents one seldom finds a sentence without any abbreviations. Parchment was not cheap, nor was scribal labour. The same applies to manuscripts in any European language, at least in my experience (mostly Latin and Dutch). Some genres are more likely to contain fewer abbreviations than others, such as literary works written in book script; but even an illustrated Bible will usually be full of them. A few arbitrary examples, with abbreviations in bold:

http://www.sothebys.com/content/dam/stb/lots/L12/L12242/009L12242_6CB6T.jpg

> Regnante d**omi**no n**ost**ro ih**s**u xp**ist**o cum post passionem sua**m** resurrectione**m** et ascensione**m** eius co**n**uersis  ad d**omi**n**u**m cunctis finib**us** terre nec in angulo occeani aliquis se a colore fidei absconderet in co**n**veniendo p**o**p**u**lo**s** in unu**m** et reges ut servirent d**omi**no. fuit in britanni(a)e partib**us** rex quidam d**e**o notus tam uita qua**m** nomine qui religiosus...

That's 32% of words.

http://www.villa.culture.fr/mediatheque/communs/images/grandFormat/0/21_2.jpg

> Pars **est** p**ri**ma prudencie: ip**s**am cui p**re**ceptur**us** sis estimare p**er**sonam. Neq**ue** enim formator ag**ri**cole deb**et** artib**us** **et** eloquencia rethores emulari q**uo**d a plerisq**ue** factum **est** q**ui** dum diserte loqunt**ur** rusticis assecuti sunt, ut eorum doct**ri**na n**on** a dis?tissimis possit intelligi. S**ed** nos recidam**us** p**re**fationis moram: ne quos rep**re**hendim**us** imitemur. ...

That makes 43%.

On the other hand, there are also manuscripts that use few abbreviations:

http://www.europeanaregia.eu/sites/www.europeanaregia.eu/files/manuscripts/regiacarol_lat_5763.jpg

> Gallia est omnis diuisa in partes tres, quarum unam incolunt belgae, aliam aquitani, tertiam qui ipsorum lingua celtae, N**ost**ra galli appellantur. Hi omnes lingua institutis legibus inter se differunt. Gallos ab aquitanis garunna flumen a belgis matrona **et** sequana diuidit. Horum omnium fortissimi sunt belgae propter ea q**uo**d a cultu atq**ue** humanitate provinciae longissime absunt minimeque ad eos mercatores saepe com**m**eant atq**ue** ea quae ad effeminandos animos pertinent inportant proximique s**un**t germanis qui trans renu**m** incolunt quib**us**cum continenter bellum gerunt ...

That's 11%.

The overall ratio is difficult to establish (and perhaps less necessary), but you can get a fair impression by looking at a couple of documents in Google Images.

Comment: Wouldn't ihsu xρisto be in fact Iesu Christo, using the Greek chi and ro?

Comment: @JDF: Yes, indeed. But isn't that what I supplied?

Comment: You wrote Xpisto. I'm just saying that that is still abbreviated (sort of).

Answer (score 11):

The proportion of abbreviated words in a medieval manuscript depends on the time when it was written and also the individual scribe, but could generally be quite high. I believe that the estimate by Cappelli cited in the question is rather conservative.

As an example, consider the following excerpt from an 11th century manuscript, containing verses 137 to 143 from the first book of Ovid’s *Metamorphoses*. (It is the top of the first undamaged column; I didn’t compare the number of abbreviations to other parts before choosing this.)

[image: excerpt from the page 1 verso of Pal. lat. 1699]

([Pal. lat. 1699, page 1 verso](http://digi.ub.uni-heidelberg.de/diglit/bav_pal_lat_1669/0006), top of the right column; courtesy of Heidelberg university library)

Here is my transcription, with those words that contain abbreviations in italics:

> nec *tantum* segetes *alimenta*-*que* debita diues
>   *poscebatur* *humus* *sed* *itum* *est* in uiscera *terrae*
>   quas-*que* recondiderat stigiis-*que* admouerat unbris
>   *effodiuntur* opes irritamenta malorum
>   iam-*que* nocens *ferrum* ferro-*que* nocencius *aurum*
>   *prodierat* *prodit* *bellum* *quod* pugnat *utroque*
>   sanguinea-*que* manu crepitantia *concutit* arma

If you count each enclitic *-que* (except as part of *uterque*) as a separate word, there are 46 words in this section, with 23 of them (50%) having been abbreviated. If you consider *alimentaque* etc. as a single word, there are 40 words, of which 22 (55%) contain an abbreviation.

In my (limited) experience, this is not abnormally high.